# How do I make a stack of boxes using Mermaid?

Tags: diagram, mermaid, stacked-bar-chart

I'm working on some documentation that will be read on Github, and I'd like to generate some diagrams using Mermaid.

Most of the flowcharts will be straight-forward, and I can follow Mermaid's examples. I'm having some trouble expressing one kind of diagram though.

I'd like to nest some boxes inside of a top-level box, for a result that looks like this:

```
    ---------------
    | My Main Box |
    |             |
    |  ---------- |
    |  |  Foo   | |
    |  ---------- |
    |  |  Bar   | |
    |  ---------- |
    |  |  Baz  |  |
    |  ---------- |
    ---------------
```

I've been scratching my head trying to come up with a way to do it, and I keep coming up empty. The closest I've been able to get is this:

```
    graph BT
        subgraph main[My Main Box]
        1[foo]---2[bar]
        2---3[baz]
        linkStyle default fill-opacity:0,stroke-width:0px,stroke-opacity:0
    end
```

which is close, but the interior boxes are too far away from each other. Is there any way for me to shorten the length of my invisible connectors, or maybe a different/better way I could express this diagram?

Comment: No. I must have mixed the URLs in the clipboard.
Here is the URL I wanted to share
https://github.com/mermaid-js/mermaid/issues/3307
PS: Deleted the wrong URL as I could not edit it anymore..

Comment: First-class support for this kind of diagram should land in Mermaid v11 – [feat: Add packet diagram by sidharthv96](https://github.com/mermaid-js/mermaid/pull/4839).

Answer (score 1):

You can tweak Gantt chart a bit:

```
%%{
  init: {
    'theme': 'base',
    "gantt": {
        "useWidth": "300"
    }
  }
}%%

gantt
    title My Main Box
    dateFormat X
    tickInterval 1day

    section  
    Foo   : 0, 1
    Bar   : 0, 1
    Baz   : 0, 1
```

[image]